# Not able to set Size property for Conditional Formatting

Tags: c#, excel, font-size, conditional-formatting

I want to add conditional formatting on a range depending on some condition.

I want to to format the Color, Size , Bold etc properties. I am able to modify Color, Bold properties but when i try to modify Size property it throws an exception "Unable to set the Size property of the Font class".

Can anyone help how can i set the Size property of Conditional Formatting object.

It is not possible to set subscript or superscript property also.

Note : These properties are not Read-Only also.

```
            FormatCondition format =(FormatCondition)( targetSheet.get_Range("A1:A10",
            Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreater,
            "100", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));

            format.Font.Bold = true;
            format.Font.Color = 0x000000FF;
            format.Font.Size = 14;
            format.Font.Subscript = true;
```

To make clear the actual usecase lets take an example where i have data of 10*10 in excel. This 10*10 is a single Range with its own format. For E.g A1 to J10. Now if i select any cell of this range then its corresponding Rows and Columns should get a Conditional Formating and it would have its own formats. This includes different fill color, different font size, change in border etc. Such as if i select cell D4 then Range A4:J4 and D1:D10 will have conditional formats applied.This can be done by applying formats on these both range and choosing type as Expression and its formula as true. Now if i select any other cell then the formats of A4:J4 and D1:D10 cells should be reverted back and the rows and colummn for the currently selected cell should be highlighted.

We can change the format such as only the Color or pattern. But its not possible to set the Size. Can anyone explain me why is it so.
Changing the size from User Interface is possible. i.e using the Format option of conditional formatting. Using that the font size,color etc of the cells which satisfies the condition can be changed.

Things which are possible from UI should be possible from code also.

Have share an image to get a view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g1qq.jpg

Comment: As Jendrik pointed out, Excel explicitly states that "For Conditional Formatting you can set Font Style, Underline, Color, and Strikethrough." All other options are greyed out when you try to do this manually, as well.

Comment: I have the same issue with the `Bold` property. It works on *most* machines, but I have two cases where an exception is thrown. It's really strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (you can change the color values and add additional properties for font size, color, etc.):

```
Dim fontSize As Variant
Dim fontType As Variant
Dim fontBold As Variant
Dim cellIn As Variant

Sub setVars()

    With Range("A1")
        fontSize = .Font.Size
        fontType = .Font.Name
        fontBold = .Font.Bold
        cellIn = .Interior.Color
    End With


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:J10")

    With r
        .Font.Size = fontSize
        .Font.Name = fontType
        .Font.Bold = fontBold
        .Interior.Color = cellIn
    End With

    With r.Rows(Target.Row)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    With r.Columns(Target.Column)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: One thing to note is that this will affect cells outside of `r`, so you may want to do a check `If Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then (Don't do anything) Else (Do Stuff) End If`. Keep in mind that `Target` will always be the top-left cell of any selection.

Comment: Thanks Zairja for quick response. In example provided here, you paint the formats of Range A1:J10 by r.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
r.Font.Bold = False explicitly but I have no idea what the formats on A1:J10 will be as they may be already on sheet. The code given will override the formats with ColorIndex=10 & Bold=False. I need to preserve the formats of A1:J10. If i just comment these two lines of your code
r.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
r.Font.Bold = False
then my old formats are not preserved.
And as suggested it is possible to change the size of a range but in that case it wont preserve old size.

Comment: @RonakNisar See my edit. You will have to store the formatting in variables (else copy the original formatting to a sheet that won't be altered and copy/paste the format from there). Run `setVars()` first (you could even add it to a workbook_open function, just make sure you explicitly reference the sheet). Please accept my answer since I have answered several questions. If you have more questions, then please post them as new, separate questions rather than adding more onto this one. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

My research said: "You can't change the font in Conditional Formatting".

I would do it like that in VBA:

```
For Each cell In Range("A1:A10")
    With cell
          .Font.Bold = true
          .Font.Color = 0x000000FF
          .Font.Size = 14
    End With
Next
```

Comment: But then how it allows editing the Color, Bold, Italic, FontStyle, Underline etc. It gives exception in some of its properties. If u cant change font of Conditional Formatting then it must not allow for any of the properties. And the solution u gave is applying formatting on Cell directly. I want to preserve the old formats of the cell. Using Conditional formatting if i delete the formats old format of that range are preserved automatically.

Comment: @RonakNisar Additionally, there isn't a way to check if conditional formatting is being applied to a cell, so you'd have to perform the same test on the cell's value (e.g. A1 > 100). That said, perhaps you can use a `Worksheet_Change` event that updates the cell's formatting based on its value, then if the value changes it will revert back to the previous formatting. You may also want a function that disables the formatting altogether or else any formatting change you try to change will keep going back into effect. Or you could have a single sub apply the formatting and another remove it.

Comment: We dont want to use Worksheet_Change event because we are already doing some other processing on that event.

Comment: @Zairja Have added a new question to the same thread to make the usecase more clear.